# How can I use adb to uninstall an APK from multiple connected devices?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, shell, adb

`adb uninstall <package name>` works when 1 device is connected.

How can I make this work for 5+ devices that are connected?

Comment: Funny, you've already asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610733/how-can-i-adb-install-an-apk-to-multiple-connected-devices . It's the same with a different command.

Comment: it doesn't because install requires the device id, as uninstall does not.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here is a simple script I use to execute adb commands over all my devices , should work under Linux and MacOsX .

You might need to adapt it to your development environment .

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script adb+
# Usage
# You can run any command adb provide on all your current devices
# ./adb+ <command> is the equivalent of ./adb -s <serial number> <command>
#
# Examples
# ./adb+ version
# ./adb+ install apidemo.apk
# ./adb+ uninstall com.example.android.apis

adb devices | while read line
do
    if [ ! "$line" = "" ] && [ `echo $line | awk '{print $2}'` = "device" ]
    then
        device=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`
        echo "$device $@ ..."
        adb -s $device $@
    fi
done
```

Comment: I get the error `head: illegal line count -- -1`

Comment: @SheehanAlam what os are you using ? seems you are not using the head command from the GNU coreutils .

Comment: @SheehanAlam I updated it the script it should work now with MacOSX .

Comment: Thanks Rabgs! I tried running this `sh uninstall.sh` but now not getting any of the echoes etc.

Comment: Is `adb devices` giving you any active devices ? and what does uninstall.sh contain ?

Comment: @SheehanAlam Put the script code provided by Rabgs into a file named adb+, then add it to your PATH in .bashrc or .bash_profile, then you can run the adb commands like normal, but just use adb+ instead of adb. The script takes in the parameters from adb+ {arg1} {arg2} and runs your adb command for each device.

Comment: Awesome. I've put it as a function to .bashrc (running linux Mint17.3). Use this link as guidance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6212408/2369484

Answer (score 27):

To uninstall the package when multiple devices are connected, you can use the following commands.

1. `adb devices` This will output a list of connected items.

   ```
   List of devices         attached  
   1234c112fsasfl          device  
   53fsks22323233          device  
   192.168.56.101:5555     device
   ```
2. `adb -s your_device_key uninstall your_package_name`.

   ```
   $ adb -s 1234c112fsasfl uninstall com.test.sample

   success - (if the device contains the apk with the specified package name)  
   failure - (if the device did not contain the apk with the specified package name)
   ```

Comment: This is the perfect solution, saved me hours of debugging

Answer (score 1):

You would have to write a script that calls adb multiple times and on each run it specify the serial number for each attached device with the -s switch.

An alternative is to use the [Android Maven plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/) which can just iterate through all attached devices (or emulators or devices only). See the i[nteraction with devices chapter](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/android-dev-sect-device.html) in the book Maven: The Complete Reference I wrote.

Also not that the multi device interaction of the Android Maven plugin also works for push, pull, install and running tests..

Comment: I guess the script was just written by Rabgs for you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In JAVA:

```
public class main {
    private final static String packageName = "com.mypackage.xxx";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        new main().doStuff();
    }

    private void doStuff() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

        String command = "adb devices -l";
        Process pr = rt.exec(command);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> devices = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
        String l = "";
        while ((l = bf.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] res = l.split("\\s{2,}");
            if (res.length == 2) {
                HashMap<String, String> device = new HashMap<String, String>();
                device.put("serial", res[0]);
                device.put("name", res[1]);
                devices.add(device);
            }
        }

        String commandUninstall = "adb -s %s uninstall %s";
        for (HashMap<String, String> map : devices) {
            String serial = map.get("serial");
            String finalCommanUnisntall = String.format(commandUninstall, serial, packageName);
            System.out.println(finalCommanUnisntall);

            Process pr2 = rt.exec(finalCommanUnisntall);
            BufferedReader bf2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr2.getInputStream()));
            String l2 = "";
            while ((l2 = bf2.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(l2);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I realise that this question already has an accepted answer, but:

```
for d in $(adb devices -l | sed '1d' | sed '$d' |  awk '{print $1}'); do adb -s $d uninstall your.pkg.id.here; done
```

The sub-command first:

1. enumerate all connected devices
2. strip the first line
3. strip the final line
4. print the first column (device identifier)

Then the outer for-loop:

1. for each device identifier
2. uninstall your.pkg.id.here from the specified device