# Adb push * not working

Tags: android, adb, push

I am running into a weird adb problem.

I am running root on the phone have full access to the device. I using sudo on my linux box.

I am able to do "adb push file_name" for an individual file, but if I do "adb push *" ina folder for group of files, i get the error "Read only filesystem"

Can anyone tell what the problem is?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20271342/how-to-install-multiple-android-applications-from-apk-files-into-device

may help

Comment: adb push can take 2 arguments, your shell expands the * before passing the result to adb. try `adb push file1 file2` to see how that works