# ADB over WiFi to multiple devices

Tags: android, adb

I would like to know is it possible to connect to multiple devices using TCP (adb connect x.x.x.x) and then send commands to all of them at same time?

For example get 3 devices, put them on same subnet, connect and then open settings screen on all of them at the same time using adb shell am start -n com.android.settings/.Settings.

I know you can do something like this using USB cables, you can even list both devices in eclipse but is this possible using wireless connection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I adb install an apk to multiple connected devices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610733/how-can-i-adb-install-an-apk-to-multiple-connected-devices)

Comment: @EvZ Not a duplicate, it needs a additional step to connect to all the deices, before we can use the answer in the link you provide

Comment: Did you get a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, store the below command in your bashprofile to ping all devices in parallel (all at once).

`alias adball="adb devices | egrep '\t(device|emulator)' | cut -f 1 | xargs -t -J% -n1 -P5 adb -s % \"\$@\""`

And now simply call adb commands.

For example, I have two devices connected (connected via Wifi in my case. But this logic also works for usb connection). And I wanted to know their window sizes. Then do:

`adball shell wm size`

**Output:**

**adb -s 172.30.132.4:5555 shell wm size**

**adb -s 172.30.16.95:5555 shell wm size**

**Physical size: 1080x2400**

**Physical size: 1440x2960**

**Override size: 1080x2220**

Comment: for me it's `grep -P '\t(device|emulator)'` but I'm still getting `xargs: invalid option -- 'J'`

Comment: found it. `-P` must be `-i` which places the argument at the position of `%` . Thus `alias adball="adb devices | grep -P '\t(device|emulator)' | cut -f 1 | xargs -t -i% -n1 -P5 adb -s % \"\$@\""`