# Android: set package name depending on device running on

Tags: android, gradle, automation, teamcity

I have functional autotests for some SDK (as aar-libs) and TeamCity CI server with several Android devices and emulators connected on.
If I use gradle to run my tests (`./gradlew connectedDebugAndroidTest`), all tests will run on each device, but each next results will overwrite previous ones and TeamCity will show only the last results.

I have to distinct these results and should know which results from what device/emulator.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to create additional build configuration on Team City, which will [parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610733/how-can-i-adb-install-an-apk-to-multiple-connected-devices) all connected devices from `adb devices` and trigger all other configurations passing device name as parameter